# Qt and win32 ,How to make win32 window that is full sceen to disable all keystrokes

Tags: c++, winapi, qt, win32gui

im trying to take Qmain Window and make it full screen that only few keystrokes could be enabled . in pure Qt it coulnd be done , you will still have keystrokes that ignoring the Qt event handler . like the windows key .
so i was thinking about mixing pure win32 and Qt to make it work. 
but i have no idea how to mix the 2 . or there any other trick for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by MiX? You can use showFullScreen() for QMainWindow, and after that, use `hooks from WinAPI` for catching special keys (for example at Main function).

Comment: yes this is what i mean , how to create this hooks , i know its cross platform i need it only for win32

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `QWidget::grabKeyboard()`